# Why does hybridization produce a more stable structure?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hybridization

I am aware of the fact that hybridization does not ALWAYS produce a stable structure (example: PH3) 
However, my question is, what makes hybrid orbitals so effective in forming stable bonds? Although exceptions like PH3 do exist, what makes hybridization the best option for stability most of the time?
Is it due to the fact that the unequal lobes formed ensure greater overlapping and hence more stability?

Comment: It seems that the A to this Q https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2769/48509 is what you are looking for

Comment: Atomic orbitals only exist in single atoms. If you want to make a bond with it, you need to have most of the electron density *between* the two aroms. That's why the shape of the MO is different from AOs, and "hybridisation" is *only* a way to describe the shape as a mixture of AO's shapes.